# Using TLS secret in ingress from hashicorp vault directly

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, nginx-ingress, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-secrets

How can I retrieve a tls (ssl certificate) secret from hashicorp vault into ingress?

I have deployed a microservices in kubernetes (openstack) with ingress nginx and hashicorp vault. The tls keys are stored in hashicorp vault. I have created a secretproviderclass:

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: sslspc
spec:
  provider: vault
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: sslspc
    data:
    - key: "tls.key"
      objectName: TLSKey
    - key: "tls.crt"
      objectName: TLSCert
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
  parameters:
    vaultAddress: http://vault.vault:8200
    roleName: "approle"
    objects:  |
      - objectName: TLSKey
        secretPath: "secret/data/myssl"
        secretKey: "tls.key"
      - objectName: TLSCert
        secretPath: "secret/data/myssl"
        secretKey: "tls.crt"
```

but can't use it directly in ingress. I have to create a pod which is creating a volume and map it to an environment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: depssl
  labels:
    app: appbusy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: appbusy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: appbusy
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: mysa
      containers:
      - name: appbusy
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "while true; do sleep 300;done"]
        env:
        - name: TLS.KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sslspc
              key: tls.key
        - name: TLS.CRT
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sslspc
              key: tls.crt
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sslspc
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: sslspc
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "sslspc"
```

After this I can use it in my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: sslspc
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /
          backend:
            service:
              name: myservice
              port:
                number: 80
```

Is it possible to retrieve the secret in ingress without creating an additional pod just for mapping purpose?

**Update (03/2023):**
As a result of my research, currently it is not possible. Solutions with a sidecar etc. makes it more complicated and you are using more resources. So finally I have created a simple busybox deployment to create the secrets (see above). This seems to be the easiest and less resource taking solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of vault injectors to inject the secrets using the annotations like

```
  annotations:
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-configmap: 'my-configmap'
    vault.hashicorp.com/tls-secret: 'vault-tls-client'
```

But to use these **annotations** you need to **set up** the injector mechanism in the cluster. Refer these official documentation for complete setup and for some examples. [DOC1](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-sidecar#kubernetes-sidecar) [DOC2](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/injector/examples#vault-agent-injector-examples).

Try this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEUyKjEatWg) to understand more about vault injectors.

Comment: Hi @ibram have you got any time to check the solution, is it useful?

Comment: Hi @ibram Can you please provide the sample role, service account and rolebinding that you have used in above setup. Do we have use clusterrole here or only role will work. I'm trying to replicate same  but getting error.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76365194/fetching-secret-from-external-vault-into-kubernetes-rancher-cluster