# fetching secret from external vault into kubernetes rancher Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, vault, csi-driver

Our goal is to fetch the secret from Hashicorp Vault into kubernetes cluster so secret will be encrypted and we won't save any secret data on anywhere. Trying to use SecretProviderClass way and did the installation with Helm chart. Deploying all yaml like service account, role and rolebinding and deployment but getting below errors.

Below configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: vault-test
  namespace: test-quota

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: vault-test
  namespace: test-quota
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: vault-test
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: vault-test
  namespace: test-quota

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: vault-test
  namespace: test-quota
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["serviceaccounts/token"]
  verbs: ["create"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["serviceaccounts"]
  verbs: ["get"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["get"]

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vault-test
  namespace: test-quota
  labels:
    app: vault-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vault-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vault-test
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: vault-test
      containers:
      - name: vault-test
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "while true; do sleep 300;done"]
        env:
        - name: admin
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: admin
              key: admin
        volumeMounts:
        - name: vault-test
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: vault-test
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretproviderclass: vault-test

apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: vault-test
  namespace: test-quota
spec:
  provider: vault
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: vault-test
    data:
    - key: admin
      objectName: admin
  parameters:
    vaultAddress: https://vault.dev.org
    vaultNamespace: abc
    vaultToken: xxxx
    roleName: approle
    objects:  |
      - objectName: admin
        secretPath: kafka
        secretKey:  admin
```

Error log:

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                            MESSAGE
10s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/vault-test-69f79f8b5-wrnjq    Successfully assigned test-quota/vault-test-69f79f8b5-wrnjq to k8s05
3s          Warning   FailedMount         pod/vault-test-69f79f8b5-wrnjq    MountVolume.NewMounter initialization failed for volume "vault-test" : volume mode "Ephemeral" not supported by driver secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io (no CSIDriver object)
4m29s       Warning   FailedMount         pod/vault-test-69f79f8b5-xwblr    MountVolume.NewMounter initialization failed for volume "vault-test" : volume mode "Ephemeral" not supported by driver secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io (no CSIDriver object)
4m22s       Warning   FailedMount         pod/vault-test-69f79f8b5-xwblr    Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[vault-test], unattached volumes=[vault-test kube-api-access-skfnn]: timed out waiting for the condition
10s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/vault-test-69f79f8b5   Created pod: vault-test-69f79f8b5-wrnjq
10s         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/vault-test             Scaled up replica set vault-test-69f79f8b5 to 1
```

Any leads will be apprecaited

Comment: The error message implies you are attempting to use the CSI driver/plugin instead of the Vault agent with the Kubernetes workload. Is that accurate?

Comment: yes we are using the secret storage CSI driver. I have installed through Helm chart from below link. 

https://secrets-store-csi-driver.sigs.k8s.io/getting-started/installation.htm

Comment: Have you seen https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-secret-store-driver?